# Python CLI entry point doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, entry-point

#### The Setup

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Python: 3.8.5 | pip: 20.0.2 | venv

Repo

```
.
├── build
├── dist
├── source.egg-info
├── source
├── readme.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── venv
```

`source` dir

```
.
├── config
├── examples
├── script.py
├── __init__.py
├── tests
└── utils
```

The important directories within the source directory are `config`, which contains a few `.env` and `.json` files; and `utils`, which is a package that contains a sub-package called `config`.

Running `script.py`, which references config and imports modules from `utils`, is how the CLI app  is started. Ideally when it is run, it should load a bunch of environment variables, create some command aliases and display the application's prompt. (After which the user can start working within that shell.)

I created a wheel to install this application. The `setup.py` contains an entry point as follows:

```
entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'script=source.script:main'
        ]
}
```

#### The Problem

I pip installed the wheel in a test directory with its own virtual environment. When I go to the corresponding `site-packages` directory and run `python script.py`, the CLI loads properly with the information about the aliases etc. However when I run simply `script` (the entry point) from the root directory of the environment the shell loads but I don't see any of the messages about the aliases etc., and some of the functionality which depends on the `utils` package aren't available either.

What could I be doing wrong? How can I make the command work as if it was running with all the necessary packages available?

#### Other information that may be useful

- `site-packages` has copies of `config` and `utils`
- `config` is included in the package as part of the `package_data` parameter in `setup.py` as `['./config/*.env', './config/*.json']`
- All import statements begin from `source`, i.e. `from source.utils.config import` etc.
- `which script` gives me the location as venv/bin/script, but that `bin` directory does not have the packages. (Which is expected, I think.)

Comment: Just bumping this up.